# NIFI - upload binary.zip to SQL Server as varbinary

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi, varbinary, zipf

I am trying to upload a binary.zip to SQL Server as `varbinary` type column content.

**Target Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE myTable ( zipFile varbinary(MAX) );
```

My **NIFI Flow** is very simple:

```
  -> GetFile: 
         filter:binary.zip

  -> UpdateAttribute:<br>
         sql.args.1.type  = -3    # as varbinary  according to JDBC types enumeration
         sql.args.1.value =  ???  # I don't know what to put here ! (I've triying everything!)
         sql.args.1.format=  ???  # Is It required? I triyed 'hex'

   -> PutSQL:<br>
         SQLstatement= INSERT INTO myTable (zip_file) VALUES (?);
```

What should I put in `sql.args.1.value`?

I think it should be the flowfile payload, but it would work as part of the INSERT in the PutSQL? Not by the moment!

Thanks!

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

Based on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8052
(Consider I'm sending some data as attribute parameter)

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService
import groovy.sql.Sql

def flowFile = session.get()
def lookup = context.controllerServiceLookup
def dbServiceName = flowFile.getAttribute('DatabaseConnectionPoolName')  
def tableName = flowFile.getAttribute('table_name')
def fieldName = flowFile.getAttribute('field_name')

def dbcpServiceId = lookup.getControllerServiceIdentifiers(ControllerService).find
{ cs -> lookup.getControllerServiceName(cs) == dbServiceName }

def conn = lookup.getControllerService(dbcpServiceId)?.getConnection()
def sql = new Sql(conn)


flowFile.read{ rawIn->
    def parms = [rawIn ]
    sql.executeInsert "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (date, "+ fieldName + ")  VALUES (CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) , ?) ", parms
}
conn?.close()

if(!flowFile) return
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Please condider "zip_file" in INSERT equal to "zipFile" in CREATE TABLE

Comment: As an option check out BLOB in this doc: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.15.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe there is a nifi native way to insert blob however you could use `ExecuteGroovyScript` instead of UpdateAttribute and PutSQL

add `SQL.mydb` parameter on the level of processor and link it to required DBCP pool.

use following script body:

```js
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

def statement = "INSERT INTO myTable (zip_file) VALUES (:p_zip_file)"
def params = [
  p_zip_file: SQL.mydb.BLOB(ff.read())    //cast flow file content as BLOB sql type
]
SQL.mydb.executeInsert(params, statement) //committed automatically on flow file success

//transfer to success without changes
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

inside the script `SQL.mydb` is a reference to [groovy.sql.Sql](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.htm) oblject

Comment: I used a variant of this solution. Thanks